# Why is RegionMeasure so slow when calculating intersection area of a 2D and a 3D object?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, graphics3d, computational-geometry, geometry, regions

**If you think this description is too long, you can read the problem directly**

I know normally when one wants to calculate an region, [this guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntegralsOverRegions.html) is useful. However, when it comes to calculating an intersection of a plane and a solid figure, this `Integrate` and `Boole` method seems to be complicated.

Since version 10, there are some new function related with Regions, which provide a more elegant way to express the problem, so I hoped to solve the problem this way.

Here is an example problem(from somewhere else). Suppose we want to calculate the intersection area of a tetrahedron and a plane. The classical way to solve would be like this:

```
Show[RegionPlot3D[
2 Sqrt[3] x + 6 y + Sqrt[6] z <= 3 && 
3 + 6 y >= 2 Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[6] z && 
3 + 4 Sqrt[3] x >= Sqrt[6] z && 1 + Sqrt[6] z >= 0, {x, -2, 
2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100], 
ContourPlot3D[
Sqrt[3] x == 3 y + Sqrt[6] z, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]]
```

[image]

And an classical way to solve would be like this (code taken from somewhere else):

```
Block[{dA, z},
z = z /. Solve[Sqrt[3] x == 3 y + Sqrt[6] z, z][[1]];
dA = Sqrt[1 + D[z, x]^2 + D[z, y]^2];
Integrate[
Boole[Sqrt[3] x == 3 y + Sqrt[6] z && 
2 Sqrt[3] x + 6 y + Sqrt[6] z <= 3 && 
3 + 6 y >= 2 Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[6] z && 
3 + 4 Sqrt[3] x >= Sqrt[6] z && 1 + Sqrt[6] z >= 0]*
dA, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
(*1*)
```

My attempt was to express the problem with graphic objects: `Tetrahedron` and `InfinitePlane`.

```
Graphics3D[{Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, Sqrt[3/2]}, {2/Sqrt[3], 
0, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), 
1, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), -1, -(1/Sqrt[6])}}], 
InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3], 1, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

**Problem**

However, when I tried this:

```
RegionMeasure@
RegionIntersection[
Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, Sqrt[3/2]}, {2/Sqrt[3], 
0, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), 
1, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), -1, -(1/Sqrt[6])}}], 
InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3], 1, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 0, 1}}]]
```

The code is going to evaluate forever, even some subtle change like changing `RegionMeasure` to `Area` won't help. (The analytical result seems to be relatively easy to obtain by geometry.) Am I making any mistake in this process?

My concern is that this problem is indeed quite simple, but required some effort to solve in Mathematica. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Region functions seem to be in their adolescence.  In V9, it would have been easier, in that there was no `RegionIntersection` to tempt you and you would have done the problem via analysis. `RegionMeasure@
RegionIntersection[<whatever>]` is a very general approach applied to a rather special, and simple, problem. Probably general methods are being applied that take a long time. I haven't experimented much in 10.1, but in 10.0, it was clear that `RegionIntersection` did ok if the intersection had the same dimension as the regions being intersected; otherwise, it would never finish.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Things like this `RegionMeasure@RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 2]] // AbsoluteTiming` returns unable to calculate message after about 400secs.

Comment: @Felix That (in your comment) is hard for `Integrate` too, but quick with `NIntegrate`.  `Volume` has `Method -> "NIntegrate"` but that seems to hang as well

Comment: @MichaelE2 But actually mathematica is able to calculate region intersections with different dimensions: `RegionMeasure@RegionIntersection[Ball[], InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]]` returns `\[Pi]` Immediately

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah... may be mathematica only uses integration instead of summing up the volume of two spherical caps

Comment: @Felix As I mentioned, I'm going on my memory of my experience from last summer/fall.  Some changes (improvements, presumably) have been made in V10.1.  A change sometimes improves many things but makes a few things worse, too.

Comment: A straightforward, general, if naive, approach to the computation of the intersection of the balls is this (I think): `# /. x0_ && y0_ && z0_ :> Integrate[1, {x, First[x0], Last[x0]}, {y, First[y0], Last[y0]}, {z, First[z0], Last[z0]}] & /@ List @@ BooleanConvert[Reduce[RegionMember[RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 2]], {x, y, z}] /. LessEqual -> Less, {x, y, z}], "DNF"] // Total`.   But I've left it running for a few minutes and it still hasn't finished. If spheres are not special-cased, *M* probably does things via coordinates and cylindrical algebraic decompositions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RegionMeasure chooses a method which is slow when exact non-rational coefficients are present. I will correct this for a future version. Thanks for pointing it out. In Mathematica 10 the example works fast with approximate coefficients.

```
In[1]:= Timing@RegionMeasure@N@
        RegionIntersection[
        Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, Sqrt[3/2]}, {2/Sqrt[3],
        0, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]),
        1, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), -1, -(1/Sqrt[6])}}],
        InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3], 1, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 0, 1}}]]

Out[1]= {0.241963, 1.}
```